# How to type a variable that is passed to numpy.asarray to produce a 2D float array?

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, mypy

I often write functions/methods that take some variable which can come in many forms, i.e., lists of lists, lists of tuples, tuples of tuples, etc. all containing numbers, that I want to convert into a numpy array, kinda like the following:

```py
import numpy as np

def my_func(var: 'what-freaking-type-here') -> np.ndarray:
    a = np.asarray(var, dtype=np.float64) # type: np.array[np.float] maybe?
    return a
```

Basically my question is how to type this appropriately, given that I can pass all kinds of values to this function to finally create a **2D float array** (note that this just an example and the dimensionality and type should be interchangeable):

```py
my_func([[0], [0]])
my_func([(0,), (2.3,)])
my_func(((0,), [2.3,]))
my_func(np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10))
```

I have this practice of taking all kinds of values and turning them into `numpy` arrays in a lot of places, to make working with the functions easy and intuitive. However, I have no idea how to properly type this to verify with `mypy`. Any hints?

Comment: Wouldn't those types suffice? `tuple, list, numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Is this just for documentation, or are you using some sort of `type` auditing software?

Comment: @Guimoute: I guess so, but it should be anything that is indexable I guess with 2 axis?

Comment: @hpaulj It's for documentation as well as for static type checking using `mypy`

Answer (score 1):

Try the [numpy-stubs: experimental typing stubs for NumPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs).

It defines the type of the `np.array()` function like this:

```py
def array(
    object: object,
    dtype: _DtypeLike = ...,
    copy: bool = ...,
    subok: bool = ...,
    ndmin: int = ...,
) -> ndarray: ...
```

Which takes any `object` for the contents and returns an `ndarray` type.

It's a work in progress. Do report back if it's effective at this stage.

There's also an older project [numpy-mypy](https://github.com/machinalis/mypy-data/tree/master/numpy-mypy). As it points out,

> Quite a few numpy methods are incredibly flexible and they do their best to accommodate to any possible argument combination. ... Although this is great for users, it caused us a lot of problems when trying to describe the type signature for those methods.

It defines the type of the `np.array()` function like this:

```py
def array(object: Any, dtype: Any=None, copy: bool=True,
          order: str=None, subok: bool=False,
          ndmin: int=0) -> ndarray[Any]: ...
```

Which takes `Any` for the contents (no type checking there) and returns an `ndarray` type that's parameterized (generic) by the element type.